# Using .each inside .each

Tags: jquery

I have JSON string which has nested array of objects like this

```
[{
    "date": 1412966290618,
        "memberInfo": {
        "firstName": "Antonio",
            "lastName": "Smith"
    },
        "service": [{
        "id": null,
            "desc": "Advice"
    }, {
        "id": null,
            "desc": "3rd Party Contact"
    }],
        "commentList": [{
        "createDate": "10/10/2014",
            "cmntType": "Notes",
            "cmntText": "A positive attitude can destroy every negative obstacle."
    }, {
        "createDate": "10/10/2014",
            "cmntType": "Notes",
            "cmntText": "I am blessed my grateful heart is the fountain of gladness"
    }]
}]
```

and I am trying to use $.each() to loop all elements. I am able to read value for "date" and "memberInfo" but not able to ready/access other two. I am trying like

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    var date = value.date;
    var memberName = value.memberInfo.firstName + ' ' + value.memberInfo.lastName;
    var serviceList = '';
    $.each(data.service, function (srvindex, service) {
      serviceList += '[' + service.id + ', ' + service.desc + ']';
    });
    var cmntList = '';
    $.each(data.commentList, function(cmntindex, cmnt) {
      cmntList += '[' + cmnt.createDate+ ', ' + cmnt.cmntText + ']';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should be using `value.service` and `value.commentList` instead of `data.service` and `data.commentList`

Comment: ...and `value.commentList`.